# Как по событию .submit отловить нажатую button?

Tags: javascript, html, form, coffeescript

Есть форма с двумя кнопками.

```
<form>
  <!-- поля формы -->
  <button type="submit"></button>
  <button type="submit" name="printing"></button>
</form>
```

Так устроена логика, что `name` на сервер не приходит и определить по нему какая копка нажата не получится (на сервере).
Но в js есть обработка отправки формы на сервер, поэтому хочу разместить немного логики там.
Внутри формы

```
_this.submit (event) ->
        event.preventDefault()
        //.......
        // здесь отлавливаю кнопку, которая нажата и ее атрибуты
 $.post $(this).attr('action')
        , $(this).serialize() + printing
        , (data) ->
        //.......
```

Как определить какая кнопка нажата? и получить ее атрибуты

Comment: подписываешься на клик по кнопке и по событию  забираешь event.target - это и будет нажатая кнопка

Comment: в event.target у меня вся форма

Comment: Внутри .submit подписаться на клик?

Answer (score 0):

без jQuery  можно реализовать так:
уже что именно от кнопки отправлять - решать самому.. адрес отправки тоже.

```js
const  form  = document.querySelector('#form')
const request = new XMLHttpRequest();

document.querySelectorAll('.submit').forEach(item=>{
  item.addEventListener('click',(ev)=>{
  const  formData = new FormData(form)
  ev.preventDefault();
  const button = ev.target;
  request.open("POST", "http://example.com");
  formData.append('action',button.getAttribute('action'))
  request.send(formData);
})})
```

```html
<form id = "form">
  <input type = "text" name= 'text'/>
  <input class = 'submit' action = "print" id = "1" type="submit"/>
  <input class = 'submit' action = "show"   id = "2" type="submit"/>
</form>
```